# YouTube Live Streaming API doesn't allow to set enableEmbed to true,

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

While both documentation and API explorer apparently allows to do that setting enableEmbed to true fails with "Embed setting was invalid".
If already set to true (using the Studio UI) it is possible to update LiveBroadcast's contenDetails confirming enableEmbed to true so it looks that the change from API from false to true is what returns the error.

Any way to set enableEmbed to true as default for the account or to update the Broadcast with the desidered value?